# Unity3d does not get code from monodevelop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard

I have a problem with my Unity project. The project is to build a simple PackMan game, but it seems that the game-engine does not get the code from the IDE. I have read that there are others that have the same problem. Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PacManMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 0.4f;  
    Vector2 destPoint = Vector2.zero;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        destPoint = transform.position;
    }
    void    Update(){
    }
    //when using physincs better use FixedUpdate!!!
    void FixedUpdate(){
        //moving toward the destination
        Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, destPoint, speed);
        rigidbody2D.MovePosition(p);

        if ((Vector2)transform.position == destPoint) {
            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow) && valid (Vector2.up))
                destPoint = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow) && valid (Vector2.right))
                destPoint = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right;
            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow) && valid (-Vector2.up))
                destPoint = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow) && valid (-Vector2.right))
                destPoint = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.right;
        }
    }

    bool valid (Vector2 dir){
        //cast line
        Vector2 pos = transform.position;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast (pos + dir, pos);
        return(hit.collider == collider2D);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the file containing this script named PacManMovement.cs?

Comment: Yes.I've added the script to the packman object in Unity and still it's not working.

Comment: are you updating the correct script? If you click the code inside the Project window, does it show the updated code inside the Inspector?

Comment: Yes, it shows the updated code.

Comment: Code works just fine for me. did you attach the riggidbody 2d to the same object ?

Comment: yes, the riggidbody is attached to the same game object.Could the problem be in the settings between unity and monodevelop?

Comment: What "does not get the code" mean? What are the symptoms of the problem you're having, exactly?

Comment: When i start the game everything works -- animation of the packman, the packman does not fall through the scene, but when i'm pressing the arrow keys the packman does not move. In addition there are no error displayed when i start the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this approach:

- Use Unity to create the C# script (**Assets** > **Create** > **C# Script**).
- In Unity, double-click the script name to open it in your preferred editor (Mono Develop, Visual Studio, etc.).
- Write your script, and make sure that you save it.
- In Unity check the script's preview pane, it should display (some of) your newly written code.
- Make sure that the script is attached as a component to the proper GameObject.

You can change your preferred editor from **Edit** > **Preferences** -> **External Script Editor**.

Comment: Done that, it's even in a separate folder. I have attached it to the GameObject and still nothing happens.

Comment: Then the problems lies in your code. Try debug it, for example you could try make valid always return true and see if your character moves then. Also you are not showing in your code where `destPoint` is set. Currently it seems to always be equal to the start position.

Comment: Thank you mate, found the problem. It seems that the first cond. statement if ((Vector2)transform.position == destPoint) is blocking the control keys.

Comment: There's where Debug.Log comes in handy. Always trace your code in order to know what's going on.